# Spatial downscaling of MODIS LST grids using a covariate (e.g. NDVI): available software?

Tags: r, remote-sensing, modis

I have a MODIS MOD11A2 (LST) grid, which has a spatial resolution of 1000m. For the purpose of Surface Energy Balance modelling, I'm trying to improve the resolution of this data to 250m, using a covariate like the NDVI. Lots of literature is available on this topic, with various titles and subjects like "spatial downscaling', 'downscaling co-kriging', etc.

I've been looking for software that is capable of performing this operation for me. Since I'm a R user, I was happy to find the *dissever* package (https://github.com/pierreroudier/dissever). However, this package seems like it is no longer maintained, and some errors prohibid me from using the package.

Does anyone know a working sofware package, preferably in R or Python, that is capable of performing such spatial downscaling?

Comment: Though not part of the classical downscaling literature, we had some good success using empirical orthogonal teleconnections for this purpose (though not via covariates). You could try to adapt the example we outline here https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v065i10

Comment: `dissever` works with `caret`... If you have error with different versions of `caret` package, modify the code to adapt it into the latest format, or, install an [old version of this package](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/caret/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used a robust regression approach, for downscaling of climate data, with consistent success. The idea is that you treat the lower-resolution data as the dependent variable, as a sample or population, and sample the higher-resolution data, treating it as the independent variable, to build a bivariate (or even multivariate) regression model. You then estimate the model to the higher-resolution data. You can do this using a variety of statistical models but, robust regressions can handle data with a very large *n* without introducing too much bias.

There is an function in the [spatialEco](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatialEco/index.html) 1.0-0 R package for downscaling rasters. Here is an example from the functions help.

```
library(raster)
library(spatialEco)

elev <- raster::getData('alt', country='SWZ', mask=TRUE)
tmax <- raster::getData('worldclim', var='tmax', res=10, lon=8.25, lat=46.8)
  tmax <- crop(tmax[[1]], extent(elev))

tmax.ds <- raster.downscale(elev, tmax, scatter=TRUE)
  print(tmax.ds$model)
  cat("Mean Square Error", tmax.ds$MSE, "\n")

  par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    plot(tmax, main="Temp max")
    plot(elev, main="elevation")
    plot(tmax.ds$downscale, main="Downscaled Temp max")
```

[image: results of downscale function]

Comment: Thank you for your solution! However, your functions calls psi.hampel,  which belongs to namespace MASS. spatialEco does not have a active Github, where can I file this "bug?" :)

Comment: All you have to do is put psi.hampel in quotes,  which I forgot.

Comment: I have not yet pushed this code to the GitHub repository (will update today) but, for future reference the package is at: https://github.com/jeffreyevans/spatialEco

Comment: I don't know why but when I want to run this method it returns error: Warning message:
In raster.downscale(elev, tmax, scatter = TRUE) :
  Population is being used and may cause memory issues

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhrari This is not an error. As stated it is a warning regarding the size of the problem that is resulting from the arguments that you are passing to the function. An error and warning are specific things in R and are not the same. Often authors put warnings in their functions to warn of a potential issue that may arise as a result of your data, parameters or combination of arguments. This warning has to do with passing a huge amount of data to R and potentially ending up with memory errors.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans that's right. However after this message, I don't know why but no output created.

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhrari can you please file a bug report here: https://github.com/jeffreyevans/spatialEco and please include code

Comment: @JeffreyEvans It solved. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to run a regression between the 1km MODIS-NDVI and MODIS-LST layers. Then assuming you obtain a good model fit, apply this model to the corresponding 250m NDVI layer. I have used [robust linear regression](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/robust-regression/) in the past with ok results.

This is fairly straight forward to run using raster function. I might have some code i can dig out if required